# Why does Firefox debounce positioned elements top / left / bottom / right changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, scroll, rendering

**Is this a Firefox bug, or am I doing something wrong?**

Changing the `top` value of a positioned element many times (for instance while a user drags an other element) works on all mainstream browsers as far as I could test, but Firefox which seems to debounce these changes.

Here's a working example under Chrome:
[image]

And a failing one under Firefox *(notice that the attribute is updated in the dev tool, but the page stays out of sync until the events stop being fired)*:
[image]

You can try it at http://ec2-13-58-57-41.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/components

**Quick note:**

You might tell me to just use the browser's scroll so here's my reason for doing what I described:

I find it practical to have a `Scroller` React Component wrapping content:

- it makes it easy to control the style of all of my scrollbars for any browser, depending on a theme and on the state of the application (like displaying them only when the content is hovered for instance)
- it provides a single development interface for regular scrolling and virtual scrolling

Comment: Isn't your problem related to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects ?

Comment: I don't think it's quite that: this article points out that the `onScroll` DOM event is asynchronously fired, and that a lag can occur between render and it, whereas here we see a lag between the `top` attribute update and render. Thanks for the interesting read though!

Comment: As a potential workaround, you could try manipulating the DOM only within a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) callback, instead of immediately after receiving the drag event from the user. That is, set a `scrollY` variable when dragging the scroll bar, and within `requestAnimationFrame`, set `top` in the DOM to `scrollY` if `scrollY` has changed.